# Error: cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs unless `otypes` is set

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I tried to connect to twitter API. I have a lookup table looks like:

```
ID  LAT LON RADIUS
1    XX  XX  XX
2    XX  XX  XX
```

And then my code is shown below:

```py
for contents in lookup:
    lat=contents[1]
    lon=contents[2]
    radius=contents[3]

    tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search, geocode=(lat,lon,radius)).items(1000)
```

And then it gives me the error that:

> Error: cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs unless `otypes` is set

Has anyone met this problem before and do you have any ideas to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the error-message it seems your code uses [`np.vectorize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012564/cannot-call-vectorize-on-size-0-inputs-unless-otypes-is-set). Please [edit] and post the full error-output (including stack traceback). Also add a [example] with related tags for used modules like [tag:numpy] - not sure [tag:tweepy] is relevant here.