# cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs unless `otypes` is set

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, fast-ai

```
class CustomImageItemList(ImageList):
    def custom_label(self,df, **kwargs)->'LabelList':
        """Custom Labels from path"""
        file_names=np.vectorize(lambda files: str(files).split('/')[-1][:-4])
        get_labels=lambda x: df.loc[x,'lesion']
        #self.items is an np array of PosixPath objects with each image path
        labels= get_labels(file_names(self.items))
        y = CategoryList(items=labels)
        res = self._label_list(x=self,y=y)
        return res

def get_data(bs, size):
    train_ds = (CustomImageItemList.from_folder(path, extensions='.jpg')
                    .random_split_by_pct(0.15)
                    .custom_label(df)
                    .transform(tfms=get_transforms(flip_vert=True),size=size)
                    .databunch(num_workers=2, bs=bs)
                    .normalize(imagenet_stats))
    return train_ds

 data=get_data(16,224)
```

I am using Fast.ai framework for image classification but the previous line runs, I get the following error "cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs unless `otypes` is set".
Any suggestions as to how this can be avoided?

Comment: Why are you using `np.vectorize` instead of a list comprehension?  `np.vectorize` adds a lot of baggage, including this need to test for a return dtype.  When `self.items` is empty it raises this error because there's nothing to test and use the define a dtype.  `np.vectorize` does not make the task any simpler or faster.

Comment: @hpaulj what changes do I need to make?

Comment: use a list comprehension

Comment: @hpaulj could you give me a little more insight please, thank you!

Comment: @hpaulj It works now, thanks a lot.. much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

```
    file_names=np.vectorize(lambda files: str(files).split('/')[-1][:-4])
    get_labels=lambda x: df.loc[x,'lesion']
    #self.items is an np array of PosixPath objects with each image path
    labels= get_labels(file_names(self.items))
```

replacing this with

```
    file_names=[file.split('/')[-1][:-4] for file in self.items]
    get_labels=lambda x: df.loc[x,'lesion']
    #self.items is an np array of PosixPath objects with each image path
    labels= get_labels(file_names)
```